# Removing Element from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xelement

below is the xml and i need to remove the Element SMS where code equals to "ZOOMLA". i am using C# code as below but it does not work. and gives me "object reference error"

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse (xml);
 XElement sms = (from xml2 in doc.Descendants ("SMSList").Descendants ("SMS") where xml2.Attribute ("Code").Value == code select xml2).FirstOrDefault ();
 sms.Remove ();
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
    <Parent>
        <ServiceList />
        <VoiceList />
        <SMSList>
            <SMS>
                <Code>ZOOMLA</Code>
                <Name>Zoom Limited</Name>
                <SubType>Prepaid</SubType>
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <ID>222</ID>
                        <Name>Charges</Name>
                        <CValue>1</CValue>
                        <Priority>0</Priority>
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </SMS>
        </SMSList>
        <DataList />
        <LBCOffer />
    </Parent>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently looking for a `Code` *attribute*, whereas in your XML it's an *element*. So `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't find anything and returns null, hence the exception on the next statement.

Additionally, you can just use the [LINQ to XML `Remove` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx) - that means it will remove *all* matching elements, so it won't fail if there aren't any. (If you *really* want to only remove the first match, you could always use `Take(1)` here.)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.Descendants("SMSList")
   .Descendants("SMS")
   .Where(x => (string) x.Element("Code") == code)
   .Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for which you are looking is not an attribute but element whose parent is  root element.
first load your xml string as XMLDocument and then find the SMS node.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16' ?> <Parent><ServiceList /><VoiceList /><SMSList> <SMS> <Code>ZOOMLA</Code> <Name>Zoom Limited</Name> <SubType>Prepaid</SubType> <Fields><Field><ID>222</ID> <Name>Charges</Name> <CValue>1</CValue> <Priority>0</Priority></Field></Fields></SMS></SMSList><DataList /> <LBCOffer /> </Parent>");
        XmlNode xNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Parent/SMSList/SMS[Code='ZOOMLA']");
        xNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xNode);
        XmlDocument xvDoc = xmlDoc;
```